# How to pass value from Child component (RenderFragment) to Parent page in C# Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I have a Blazor project that loads DLL that contain razor components. To render these dynamic components at client-side, I use render tree builder to create a `RenderFragment` from dynamic component and place it on the page to show the component. However, I can't find a way to bind a value while creating the render tree. Normally, I can pass data using the example below of parent and child component, but not sure how to do it when converting dynamic components to `RenderFragment`.

**Parent component**

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<ChildComponent @bind-Password="_password" />

@code {
    private string _password;
 }
```

**Child component**

```
<h1>Child Component</h1>

Password:

<input @oninput="OnPasswordChanged"
       required
       type="@(_showPassword ? "text" : "password")"
       value="@Password" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ToggleShowPassword">
    Show password
</button>

@code {
    private bool _showPassword;

    [Parameter]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> PasswordChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnPasswordChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Password = e.Value.ToString();
        return PasswordChanged.InvokeAsync(Password);
    }
    private void ToggleShowPassword()
    {
        _showPassword = !_showPassword;
    }
}
```

**Dynamic Component to `RenderFragment`**

The code below shows how I am able to show the component on the page by converting it to `RenderFragment`. Do you know how I can bind a variable at the render tree builder, to pass data from dynamic component to the parent page?

**Note:** This Dynamic Component `@dynamicComponent` is same as the Child component above and I want the password data from it.

```
@page "/{ComponentName}"
@inject IComponentService ComponentService

@if (render)
{
    @dynamicComponent()
    
    @_password;
}
    
@code{
    private string _password;
    
    [Parameter]
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    bool render = false;
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        render = true;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    
    RenderFragment dynamicComponent() => builder =>
    {
        RazorComponentModel component = ComponentService.GetComponentByPage(ComponentName);
        builder.OpenComponent(0, component.Component);
        for (int i = 0; i < component.Parameters.Count; i++)
        {
            var attribute = component.Parameters.ElementAt(i);
            builder.AddAttribute(i + 1, attribute.Key, attribute.Value);
        }
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first see if I understood you right... You want to create a sort of component renderer, which gets a component's name as a parameter, and by means of the IComponentService you gets the component's `Type`, and then render it. I also guess that the component's `Type` may be `Type Child`, and you want to know how to render it in the Index page, and gets the password entered in the Child component, right ?
The following code describes how to do that, but of course I cannot use the IComponentService service to discover the type of the component, but instead assume that the type is `Child`.

Copy and run the code snippet. Test it... It should work...

```
@page "/{ComponentName?}"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices;

@if (render)
{
    @dynamicComponent
   
}

<p>Your password: @_password</p>
@code{
    private string _password;

    [Parameter]
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }

    bool render = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        render = true;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    RenderFragment dynamicComponent => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(Child));
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "Password", _password);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "PasswordChanged", 
            EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, 
            RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(this, __value => _password = __value, _password)));
        builder.CloseComponent();

    };
}
```

Note: You should not modify the values of the parameter properties in your Child component. Parameter properties in Blazor are auto properties, meaning that you can access their values but you must not change them.

Also, you shouldn't create sequence number by a loop. Sequence numbers should be hard-coded. Googlize this subject discussed in an article by Steve Anderson.

Comment: Hi @enet. Your solution worked. Thank you. Additionally, If I want to bind a class such as `PluginData` which has a string property called `_password`, how can I modify your solution above to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you, unless you explain your request in details. However, you can pass to the dynamicComponent method parameters you can use in the code. You can also define properties outside the dynamicComponent method and access them from the method

Comment: What I meant was instead of passing a string data from child to page component, Is it possible to pass an object from child to parent component that has several properties such as username, password and more?

Comment: I was working on it previously, i switched the string property with a class that has several properties. It was supposed to work but it didn't thats why I asked for your help. I retried again just now and realized a tiny mistake that I did. Now it works. This way I can bind more data. Thank you @enet.

Comment: Yes, you can pass an object or a collection of objects...